# Python Setuptools CLI building

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-3.6, setuptools, python-packaging

I have a little trouble getting my cli built & installed correctly with `setuptools`.

My project structure looks like this :

```
foobar/

    cli/

        src/
            main
            __init__.py

        config.json
        __init__.py

    setup.py
    requirements.txt
    venv.sh
    README.md
    .gitignore 
    __init__.py
```

My `setup.py` looks like this :

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

# Package meta-data.
__version__ = '0.0.1'

# What packages are required for this module to be executed?
REQUIRED = ['requests', 'argparse']

# Where the magic happens:
setup(
    name='foobar',
    version=__version__,
    description='foo bar',
    long_description="https://github.com/foo/bar",
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    author='foo bar',
    author_email='foo@bar.com',
    packages = find_packages(),
    url='https://github.com/foo/bar',
    entry_points={'console_scripts': ['foobar=cli.src.main:main']},
    python_requires='>=3.6.0',
    install_requires=REQUIRED,
    include_package_data=True,
    classifiers=[
            "Topic :: Utilities"
    ]
)
```

All I am trying to achieve is this :

```
pip uninstall -y foobar # remove old installation
python setup.py build # build
python setup.py install # install
foobar # run the "cli.main:main"
```

This results in the following error :

```
bash: /Users/myuser/.pyenv/shims/foobar: No such file or directory
```

---

Update #1

My package is definitely getting built & installed. Because I see my packaged with I do a `pip freeze | grep foobar`. Its definitely there.

---

Update #2

My package can also be imported in a python shell as follows :

```
$ python 
Python 3.6.8 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cli
>>> import cli.src
>>>
```

No errors here ^ indicate, my package imports are fine. But I am trying to make my package accessible directly from the `cli`. Typing `foobar` should directly trigger the `cli.src.main:main` as described in my `entry_points` section. That seems to NOT work.

---

Update #3

```
$ which foobar
$ echo $?
1
```

This tells me the mapping for the cli command is not defined. I am out of options now :|. I must have messed up somewhere in the `setup.py` .. any leads will be helpful.

Comment: `pip show --files foobar`

Comment: your trick helped me, thanks @ph